# Gráfico com várias linhas

Tags: r

Tenho uma *data frame* com informações de ganho de peso em função do tempo de vários animais. Preciso *plotar* um gráfico com linhas conectadas. Contudo preciso de uma linha para cada animal em um só gráfico, todas as linhas podem ser da mesma cor. Segue o data frame:

```
Animal  Dia Ganho
5   6   0.792598868
5   7   0.69531978
5   8   0.69249055
5   9   0.67807778
5   10  0.671494999
5   11  0.655610838
6   7   0.837702569
6   8   0.842916274
6   9   0.792294277
6   10  0.842735049
6   11  0.837866445
6   12  0.795874902
8   5   0.894529667
8   6   0.849056713
8   7   0.817659919
8   8   0.716166047
8   9   0.688671429
8   10  0.69898832
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando o pacote `ggplot2`:

```
dados <- read.table(text = 
                    "Animal Dia Ganho
                    5   6   0.792598868
                    5   7   0.69531978
                    5   8   0.69249055
                    5   9   0.67807778
                    5   10  0.671494999
                    5   11  0.655610838
                    6   7   0.837702569
                    6   8   0.842916274
                    6   9   0.792294277
                    6   10  0.842735049
                    6   11  0.837866445
                    6   12  0.795874902
                    8   5   0.894529667
                    8   6   0.849056713
                    8   7   0.817659919
                    8   8   0.716166047
                    8   9   0.688671429
                    8   10  0.69898832", header = T)
dados$Animal <- factor(dados$Animal)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dados, aes(x = Dia, y = Ganho, colour = Animal)) +
  geom_line()
```

A variável `Animal` foi transformada em fator para diferenciá-los.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que ue precisava